# Using Java CDI, is there a way to intercept methods from a @Produces

Tags: java, cdi

I need create objects using CDI produces, and I want to intercept methods from this created object with CDI Interceptors as well.

I tested the injection of `SomeBean` without produces and the interceptor works. But, when the `SomeBean` is created inside a producer, the interceptor not works.

Is this the right behavior? If yes, is there a way to get arround this problem?

```
@SomeInterceptorBinding
public class SomeBean {
  public void doSomething(){
    // ...
  }
}


// inside any CDI bean
// -- when create by without @Produces method, the interceptor works, but
// -- when create inside a @Produces, the interceptor not works
@Inject
SomeBean b;
```

Thanks

Comment: I found a very ugly solution [here](https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.0.0/en-US/html/producermethods.html), at item 8.2. I will keep looking for more elegant and generic solution.

Comment: take a look at https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.0.0/en-US/html/producermethods.html#d0e3371 I guess you are creating the bean in your producer method with the *new* operator. This won't work, because the CDI container will not be aware of the created object, so it will not do any dependency injection/whatever for it. You have to create the bean through the CDI container

Comment: I found a more elegant solution, that is lookp beans programmatically (with this, the methods inside created objects are intercepted). But this do not solve may problem yet. Classes that are not registered on CDI container cannot have a programmatic lookup.

Comment: You are trying to solve a problem with your own solution  (using produces). This is bad idea. Present here your design and justify that you have to use Produces in order to solve some problem. And maybe we could come up with more elegant solution without workarounds for CDI